# How to pass List<object> to method signature method(object obj) then cast back to List<object>

Tags: c#

I have object List entity and I have to pass it to a method of a class with signature of method(object). It allows me to send a List to an object but how would I return it to object list of List?

E.G.

```
public class Sample
{
    public void passer()
    {
        List<ENT_Transaction> entityList = new List<ENT_Transaction>();
        ENT_Transaction entity = new ENT_Transaction;
        entityList.Add(entity);

        receiver(entityList);   
    }

    public void receiver(object obj)
    {
        //This is not allowed on runtime
        List<ENT_Transaction> entity = (List<ENT_Transaction>)obj;
    }
}
```

Am I doing it right or should I change the method signature to receiver(List obj) to receive a list of object List?

Comment: it will allowed, are you facing any run-time exception?

Comment: Try to use `as` keyword.

Comment: @Veljko89: It's not an instance of `List`.

Comment: sorry @Veljko89, It is good but my goal is to use object as signature since I am implementing the methods as interface

Comment: Typical XY problem. Explain what you are trying to achieve, and we will give you a proper solution. This is just messy.

Comment: Yes I experienced this twice already that I can't convert the object back to List in runtime. But I'll still look for it, maybe I have a code problem. If it looks good to everyone, maybe i'm the one who is wrong :) I'll check it out again

Comment: I think I understand it now. I remember just now, I have a method that returns a List<object> and when I cast it back to List<ENT_Transaction>, I am receiving a runtime error. It's just really my code that mess up. List<ENT_Transaction> entity = (List<ENT_Transaction>)obj is really running. Thanks every one.

Comment: @Mykola: `as` is not a solution in and of itself. By itself, it will simply trade an `InvalidCastException` for a `NullReferenceException`, which arguably _detracts_ from quickly understanding why an exception was thrown. Is using `as` a cleaner approach? Sure. But it needs appropriate null handling as well; if you want it to actually be better than the alternative.

Answer (score 2):

As per your comment you have an interface which contains the function with object argument,

So I would recommend you to use generic

Create generic function in interface

```
interface ISample<T> where T : class
{
    void receiver<T>(T obj) ;
}

public class Sample : ISample<List<ENT_Transaction>>
{
    public void passer()
    {
        List<ENT_Transaction> entityList = new List<ENT_Transaction>();
        ENT_Transaction entity = new ENT_Transaction;
        entityList.Add(entity);

        receiver(entityList);
    }        

    public void receiver<T>(T obj)
    {
        T entity = obj;
    }
}
```

Comment: The class constraint seems unnecessary to me. it prevents structs and primary types from being used.